# How to apply List<ParseUser> to MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, list, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter, multiautocompletetextview

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView in my activity. I want to get a List of usernames in my "_User" table. I already know how to do it. The problem is that the MultiAutoCompleteTextView supports only ArrayAdapter. How can I convert the result from the Parse query to match the MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your Users list you get from Parse, and extract the usernames and add them to an ArrayList. Then you can use an ArrayAdapter. Alternitively, I think you can just override the toString() in ParseUser and make it return a username and pass the user list into the ArrayAdapter. IIRC ArrayAdapter will take care of the rest